# Node, Mongo, Mongoos - Can't set headers after they are sent

Tags: node.js, mongodb, angular, express

I'm confronting a weird issue while using a simple todo MEAN application that I'm using a remote database and whenever I update or delete a record (not always but mostly), it throws the error:

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (_http_outgoing.js:357:11)
    at ServerResponse.header (E:\Examples\mean-stack-todo\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:730:10)
    at ServerResponse.json (E:\Examples\mean-stack-todo\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:253:10)
    at E:\Examples\mean-stack-todo\app\routes.js:11:13
    at E:\Examples\mean-stack-todo\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:3800:16
    at E:\Examples\mean-stack-todo\node_modules\kareem\index.js:220:48
    at E:\Examples\mean-stack-todo\node_modules\kareem\index.js:131:16
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:73:7)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:104:9)
```

This error occurs with POST and DELETE where implementations are:

```
app.post('/api/todos', function (req, res) {

    // create a todo, information comes from AJAX request from Angular
    Todo.create({
        text: req.body.text,
        done: false
    }, function (err, todo) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }

        // get and return all the todos after you create another
        getTodos(res);
    });
});
```

And DELETE:

```
// delete a todo
app.delete('/api/todos/:todo_id', function (req, res) {
    Todo.remove({
        _id: req.params.todo_id
    }, function (err, todo) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }

        getTodos(res);
    });
});
```

I don't know where the error's origin is.

Comment: what does the `getTodos(res)` does

Comment: You are sending response more than 1 time. Check `getTodos` function. And also change `res.send(err);` to `return res.send(err);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: Can't set headers after they are sent

This means you sended a reponse twice or more, that's not possible.

On error, you have to use return otherwise getTodos function will be called and I guess you respond twice, first time on error and second time in getTodos function.

```
// delete a todo
app.delete('/api/todos/:todo_id', function (req, res) {
    Todo.remove({
        _id: req.params.todo_id
    }, function (err, todo) {
        if (err) {
            // added the return
            return res.send(err);
        }

        getTodos(res);
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks it some how worked. But I'm now getting error `TypeError: Cannot read property 'electionId' of undefined` in POST and DELETE. Any Idea?

Comment: that mean you are trying to access an object property called 'electionId' on an undefined value. You need to show more code, I can't see any electionId. But from the error you are doing something like ```yourObject.electionId``` where yourObject is undefined.